# How to implement ajax call using promise with angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use angular promise using $q that is wrapped in 'service' and call it from my controller.
Here is the code:

```
var myController = function ($scope, myService) {
    $scope.doSomething = function (c, $event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        myService.method1(c).then(function (rslt) {
            alert(rslt);
        }, function (err) {
            alert(err);
        }).then(function () {
            //clean up
        });        
    };
};
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
    .factory('myService', function($q) {
        function _method1(c) {
            var dfr = $q.defer();

            var dt = { sc: c };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "mypage.aspx/mymethod",
                data: JSON.stringify(dt),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () {
                    dfr.resolve('actions sucess');
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    dfr.reject(msg);
                }
            });
            return dfr.promise;
        }
        return { method1: _method1 };
    }).controller('myController', myController);
```

The problem is that ' alert(rslt);' piece of code is never executed.
Service is called and data is updated but first 'then' function is not reached on first click.

What am I doing wrong?
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the dependency to `$rootScope` and call `$rootScope.$apply()` in both callbacks from `$.ajax()`:

```
success: function () {
    dfr.resolve('actions sucess');
    $rootScope.$apply();
}, ...
```

But better yet, use Angular's [`$http` service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http).

Comment: I don't understand why triggering the digest cycle solves this example. When you `resolve()` the promise (return of `method1(c)`, same reference), the `then()` function should trigger even **without** an `$apply`. Only thing I found in the docs is: "$q is integrated with the ng.$rootScope.Scope model observation mechanism ... which means faster propagation ...".

Comment: The integration of Angular's `$q` with Angular means it *requires* a digest cycle to trigger changes.

Comment: Interesting, this is new to me. Do you have a link to this piece of doc?

Comment: I haven't found it in the docs, but (surprize!) the [code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/q.js). See e.g. line 213 in the `resolve()` function, it calls `nextTick()` to run the callbacks. Angular's `nextTick()` is bound to the digest cycle (and the reason for this behaviour).

Comment: Lol just found the same! Cool stuff. This explains it but sadly the docs are incomplete - worse - In my opinion misleading. Thank you for explaining m8. Valuable background info. Every angular freak should look at their framework code in detail.

Answer (score 3):

I would recoomend you to use `$http` and `$resource` instead of `$.ajax`

Heres an example of `$http`

```
myApp.factory('MyService',
[
    '$http',
    '$q',
    '$resource',
function (
    $http,
    $q,
    $resource
) {
    return {
        doSomething : function (somedata) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http({ method: 'POST', url: '"mypage.aspx/mymethod"', data: somedata }).
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.resolve(true);
                }).
                error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.resolve(false);
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: can you expand on $resource ?